# How to specify web root in already active project?

Tags: phpstorm

I opened project by using File -> Open Directory.

Now I wonder how can I specify web root URL now?
It's my localhost.

Comment: Define proper deployment entry in `Settings | Deployment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools - Deployment - Configuration